# method never gets called

Tags: android

I am trying to call my method in my service from a timer like this-

```
public void run() {
                walkdir(dir);// call method

            }
```

but it never gets called or shows any toast message. am i missing something? i'm stuck with this for over an hour. here is my full code-

```
public class FreezeService extends Service {
Context context = this;
// constant
public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000; // 10 seconds
// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

// getting SDcard root path
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath());

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if already existed
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    } else {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0,
            NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;// this make the service sticky which prevents it
                        // from getting killed by advanced task killers
}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                walkdir(dir);// call method

            }
        });
    }
}

public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String Patternjpg = "x23213jdfkjsdbfnsfddns";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().contains(Patternjpg)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "method got called",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Do what ever u want
                    listFile[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A service needs to be declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: <service android:name=".FreezeService" /> already did and service is showing toasts in oncreate already so its working fine

Comment: call this function inside onStartCommand or onBind function .

Comment: change the service declaration in manifest like this ->

<service android:name=".FreezeService" android:process=":remote"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"/>

Comment: that is not an issue, my service is working fine, and showing toasts in oncreate. i already have 6 services in my project

Comment: @collie , you should check your if else condition . 
i just put the toast outside of the condition and now , it's showing the toast .

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

## Your code is correct and works as expected, BUT your pattern is not matching any file in the device you execute it.

---

## Let's prove it:

Given this folder structure:

[image]

And modifying your code a little bit to have better output and allow test in my local computer (can't test in android right now):

```
public class WalkDir {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        walkdir(new File("C:\\test"));
    }
    
    public static void walkdir(File dir) {
        String Patternjpg = "x23213jdfkjsdbfnsfddns";
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("directory found" + listFile[i].getPath());
                    walkdir(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().contains(Patternjpg)) {
                        System.out.println("method got called, deleting " + listFile[i].getPath());
                        // Do what ever u want
                        listFile[i].delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having this correct output:

```
directory found C:\test\1
directory found C:\test\2
directory found C:\test\3
directory found C:\test\3\1
method got called, deleting C:\test\3\x23213jdfkjsdbfnsfddns.js
```

---

## ADD-ON'S

Variables and method names in Java are lowerCamelCase by convention. So:

```
String patternJPG = "x23213jdfkjsdbfnsfddns";

public static void walkDir(File dir) {
```

Also, I would extract `patternJPG` variable outside `walkDir` recursive method:

```
private final String patternJPG = "x23213jdfkjsdbfnsfddns";

public void walkDir(File dir) {
     // method as is...
}
```