# copy files from assets folder to sd card in android

Tags: android

my code works fine for copying a file from assets folder to sd card. but whenever i try to copy again, it just replaces the old file with the new one instead of renaming it. how do i fix this? thanks

```
 private void copyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        if (files != null) for (String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
              in = assetManager.open(filename);
              File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
              out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
              copyFile(in, out);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }     
            finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    try {
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
          out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I can answer also this question... But **why you want to make this stuff?** Delete recursively or write infinitely does not seem a *nice* or *usual* behaviour in an app... **why you need to harm devices?**

Comment: i am working on a better device manager app and security app. this works on sms and will require your password to work :) . the write infinitely is for another project btw

Comment: i am trying to fill my memory to test out behaviour of my project, this will be included in my developer tools app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN answer is one of the ways to achieve your goal, just changing one line will do the job:

```
File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Another way is to increase file size *ad eternum*, but if you are making a tools suit this won't fit your needs.

Comment: if you dont need to create more than 2147483647 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) files, yes...

Comment: well... `++1` wont work... you need a variable.... also... tell us error or exception... *not copying* is not a great info...

Comment: this is not an error or exception... any message in stacktrace or log?

Comment: that means the original file does not exists.... `in = assetManager.open(filename);` is not finding any file...

Comment: nope, it means `assetManager.open(filename)` is not finding any file... check filename and assetManger.open usage

Comment: can you tell me how to put this in asyntask? or call this method from asynctask?

Comment: sorry, but actually threads are not my best skill... but post a new question and I'm sure someone will guide you :)

Comment: hey, can you answer this one sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303279/method-never-gets-called

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting files in case they exist is a normal behavior, Use `fileObject.exists()` method to check, If the file exists pick another filename, You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` method to gain a unique suffix and add it to the file name.

Comment: @abbie What do you mean by "until my storage is full" ?

Comment: it means keep copying files to my memory card/internal SD card (primary/secondary storage/memory) until it is full.

Comment: I think this is a litte off topic, please ask another question about it.