# Proper way of deleting files in android

Tags: android

My code is for deleting all the files having the string "hss" in their names. this works fine for all files in my internal memory, however it does Not delete files which are present in a folder.

How do I make it work?

```
public class RemoveApkTraces extends Activity {
// getting SDcard root path
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath());

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.done_ui);

    // at the end of oncreate
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ExplorerDBOperation().execute();

        }
    }, 300);
}

class ExplorerDBOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RemoveApkTraces.this, "Please wait",
                "Processing.........");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String Patternjpg = "hss";
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().contains(Patternjpg)) {
                        // Do what ever u want
                        listFile[i].delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must extract you method and use recursion (call method itself) when a folder is found:

```
String Patternjpg = "hss";

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    deleteFrom(dir);
    return true;
}

private void deleteFrom(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                // recursive call: 
                // if you find a folder, call method again!
                deleteFrom(listFile[i]); 
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().contains(Patternjpg)) {
                    // Do what ever u want
                    listFile[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** *I haven't tested code itself I just wrote method on the fly!*

Comment: @abbie have you seen the note? I don't have any ide near now but I guess you can get the idea.. think SO is to guide you with your problems, not a *please-write-code-for-me* service...

Comment: hey yeah i saw it. thanks for the answer. just wondering if you could answer this one :)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323872/copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sd-card-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You have this code in your example:

```
if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

                }
```

Put something inside the braces... you can just refactor most of your `doInBackground` method into a separate method `deleteDirectory` and call this recursively. Or you could get fancy and buily a list/stack of `Dir`'s to traverse to avoid recursion if you fear that there could be very deep directory structures.

Comment: uhmm, what should i put after that line? :/

Comment: i used to have "walkdir(listFile[i]);" after that line when i used to rename files, but it gives me error in this case. i am surprised you figured it out that quick

Comment: @abbie, see Jordis answer, he spells out what I suggested in a clear way.

Comment: And, not to sound rude, but you seem to try to program a function that potentially wipes out your (or other users') device while not having a very clear understanding of what you are doing. Careful... accidents happen. :)

Comment: i am working on a better device manager app rather than the stock google device manager :)